# How to mock Local Variables for unit testing in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have two files, `file.component.ts` containing:

```
  setTwoNumberDecimal(e) {
    const USER_VAL = parseFloat(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
    e.target.value = this.getTruncatedValue(USER_VAL, 1);
  }
```

and my test file `file.component.specs.ts` containing:

```
describe('setTwoNumberDecimal()', () => {
  it('tests commas are removed and user value is set', () => {
    const mockEvent = {target: {value: '5.777,'}};
    component.setTwoNumberDecimal(mockEvent);
    expect(component.setTwoNumberDecimal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I want to be able to check that, after `setTwoNumberDecimal(e)` is run:

1. `USER_VAL` is equal to `'5.777'` (that is, the comma has been removed); and
2. `e.target.value is equal` to `'5.77'` (that is, the last value has been truncated)

The functionality already works for the comma replace and the truncate.

Comment: You should be checking that the value is what you expect. Not sure why you would want to very that the method has ben called.

Comment: oops, sorry I meant to check that the used function was called in addition to what you told me to add. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Test that the value is what you expect it to be in your mocked event.

```
describe('setTwoNumberDecimal()', () => {
  it('Should truncate decimal from value', () => {
    const mockEvent = {target: {value: '5.777,'}};
    expect(mockEvent.target.value).toEqual('5.77');
  });
  it('Should remove commas from value', () => {
    const mockEvent = {target: {value: '1,234,567.89,'}};
    expect(mockEvent.target.value).toEqual('1234567.89');
  });
});
```

Comment: this is great, but how do I call the functionality to remove the comma for example? component.setTwoNumberDecimal(mockEvent).USER_VAL for example doesn't work because the function doesn't return any value