# How to Access Local Variables for testing in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have two files, `file.component.ts` containing:

```
  removeComma(e) {
    const USER_VAL = parseFloat(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, ''));    
  }
```

and my test file `file.component.specs.ts` containing:

```
describe('removeComma()', () => {
  it('Should remove commas from value', () => {
    const mockEvent = {target: {value: '1,234,567.85,'}};
    /* missing mock event functionality here*/
    expect(USER_VALUE).toEqual('1234567.85');
  });
});
```

I want to be able to check that, after `removeComma(e)` is run, `USER_VAL` is equal to `'1234567.89'` (that is, the commas have been removed).

The functionality already works for the comma replace.

Comment: Why are you posting this [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74483597/3001761)? In this version `USER_VALUE` isn't accessible anywhere outside `removeComma`, so it's not clear what the point of doing that even is - give a [mre].

Comment: I posted differently and tried to be more clear because I did not get the answer I needed

Comment: This is, if anything, _less_ clear. Look at the code you've actually posted - what's the point of it? What's the behaviour you'd actually test? How would you ever get access to the result to assert on it? As you can see from the useless answer below this is moving in entirely the wrong direction.

Comment: I understand that it is odd that there is no return value in the function, this is because I am using it in a (change) within my html component

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna show you what will work. I recommend that you read through some jest examples (or even the jest docs) to get the idea of this testing framework.

```
removeComma(e) {
  const USER_VAL = parseFloat(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  return USER_VAL;    
}
```

And in your test-file:

```
describe('removeComma()', () => {
  it('Should remove commas from value', () => {
    const mockEvent = {target: {value: '1,234,567.89,'}};
    const result = removeComma(mockEvent);

    expect(result).toEqual('1234567.89');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way to do this without the return statement? I actually have other functionality in the removeComma function I have not included, but I am aware it is odd for the USER_VAL to not be doing anything

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! You need to simply call the original function before the expect. Then you can access the value

```
describe('removeComma()', () => {
  it('Should remove commas from value', () => {
    const mockEvent = {target: {value: '1,234,567.85,'}};
    component.removeComma(mockEvent);
    expect(mockEvent.target.value).toEqual('1234567.85');
  });
});
```

Comment: This test _doesn't_ pass with the code in your question. And the answer to the title is still "you don't" - you test _behaviour_, not implementation.